# avoid multiple votes with ip

Tags: php, voting

I have a simple voting button, but since someone can press multiple times after reloading the site, I want to prevent using the last stored IP address. Something happened and it did not stop multiple voting from the same IP.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = "update table set votos=votos-1, lastvote='$ip' where id='$id'";
$voto = "SELECT lastvote FROM table where id='$id'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $voto);

if ($ip == $resultado) {} else{
mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
}
```

The idea was to compare the last voting IP before storing the new vote but i cant figure out what was wrong.
Thank you

Comment: you're not checking if the IP has already voted before updating the table

Comment: the update is at the end of the code.

Answer (score 1):

What if someone change his ip? what if another user vote after 1 second? Actually the concept you are using is faulty. You cant prevent multiple votes by tracking ip address. Dynamic ip address changes after after user disconnect his internet connection. And user can change ip easily by using apps. So the solution is registering user and after registration one user can cast one vote. Hope it will help.

Comment: You are right, it does not work against dynamic ip, but will be enough for a small site while i follow your idea. Sadly the code is not working.

Comment: @RicardoMehr you can use cookie to track voting then. It is also can track user. But if user clear cookie you will never be able to track.